# How to add component as child in angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a problem with using component as child. I need to load some table value when user clicks on the button it should be rendered. But I have no clue for that. Here is the example:

```
@ViewChild(ConfigurationTableComponent) tableComponent: ConfigurationTableComponent;
```

And UI like:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addElement()">Add new table row</button>
```

And the `addElement()` function:

```
  addElement(event: { stopPropagation: () => void; }) {
    this.table.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ConfigurationTableComponent);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

What I want is when I click the button it should add one more row into the table.

[image]

[Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3shau)

Comment: Show table HTML, or better a stackbiltz copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do it jQuery way. Angular way it would be something like this:

```
      <tr *ngFor="let row of elements, let i = index">
        <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.age}}</td>
      </tr>
```

```
  elements = [];

  addElement() {
    this.elements = [...this.elements, {lastName: 'Doe', firstName: 'John', age: 26}]
  }
```

Here's stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-waxqv1?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: He try to add more row, not show/hide table. Change it to ngFor and add more item to source.